# Applying Jquery class to all children of only one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get more JQuery practice.  I have an HTML page that consists of headings and paragraphs.  When the user clicks on the heading, the paragraph directly below should be enlarged.  Also, the heading should change its background color to #CCCCCC.  Finally, only one paragraph and heading should be enlarged and colored respectively.  So far I've tried:

09.js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('h2').click(function()
  {
    $(this).addClass('h2Color');
    $(this).children('p').removeClass().addClass('large');
  });
});
```

09.css

```
  .h2Color{
  background-color: #CCCCCC
  }

 .large {
 font-size: 3.0em;
 }
```

09.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Biography of Mark Twain</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="09.css" type="text/css" />

<script src="jquery.js"> </script>
<script src="09.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Title Of Page</h3>
<h1>Random H1 Element</h1>

<div>
<p>On then sake home is am leaf. Of suspicion do departure at extremely he believing. Do know said mind do rent they oh hope of. General enquire picture letters garrets on offices of no on. Say one hearing between excited evening all inhabit thought you. Style begin mr heard by in music tried do. To unreserved projection no introduced invitation. 
</p>
</div>

<div>
<h2>Marilyn Monroe</h2>
<p>I have feelings too. I am still human. All I want is to be loved, for myself and for     my talent.
</p>
<p> 
I'm selfish, impatient, and a little insecure. I make mistakes, I'm out of control, and at times hard to handle. But if you can't handle me at my worst, then you sure don't deserve me at my best.
  </p>
 </div>
 <div>
<h2>Richard Dawkins</h2>
<p>I am against religion because it teaches us to be satisfied with not understanding the world.
</p>
<p>Personally, I rather look forward to a computer program winning the world chess   championship. Humanity needs a lesson in humility.
 </p>

</div>

<div>
<h2 >John F. Kennedy</h2>
<p>
Let every nation know, whether it wishes us well or ill, that we shall pay any price, bear any burden, meet any hardship, support any friend, oppose any foe to assure the survival and the success of liberty.
</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know why it's not working.  I guess it's just something that I'm not seeing right now.  Thanks

Comment: Your ``p`` are not children of your ``h2`` elements, so ``$(this).children('p').removeClass().addClass('large');`` is going to return nothing.

Comment: The H2 doesn't have any children  ?

Comment: P is not a child of H2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `h2` element has no `children()`, therefore it affects no elements. Instead try:

```
$('h2').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('h2Color');
    $(this).closest('div').find('p').removeClass().addClass('large');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3zEXD/).

Though I'd suggest using `toggleClass()`:

```
$('h2').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('h2Color');
    $(this).closest('div').find('p').toggleClass('large');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3zEXD/1/).

Or, if you'd rather have only *one* 'enlarged' section at a time, first remove the `large` class-name from all elements, and then add it to only the clicked element:

```
$('h2').click(function () {
    $('.large').removeClass('large');
    $(this).addClass('h2Color').closest('div').find('p').addClass('large');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3zEXD/2/).

Comment: Your last code is exactly what I was looking for.  I just have one more quick question.  The code works in JS Fiddle but not when I run it in chrome or anything.  Just curious if I have to change something or whatever.  Thanks.

Comment: No, that should work directly. Are there any errors cropping up in your browser's JavaScript console (F12 in most browsers)? Have you included jQuery? Have you wrapped it in the `$(document).ready(/* your code here */)` handler?

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/yWnPK/2/)

```
  $('h2').click(function () {
      $(this).addClass('h2Color');
      $(this).next('p').removeClass().addClass('large');
  });
```

Use `.next()`, since you wanted only 1 paragraph to be enlarged

If you want all the paras to be enlarged which are related to the `h2` tag, use this

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/yWnPK/3/)

```
  $('h2').click(function () {
      $(this).addClass('h2Color');
      $(this).parent('div').find('p').removeClass().addClass('large');
  });
```

`$(this).children('p')` is wrong because `h2` cannot have a paragraph as its child.

Answer (score 0):

The paragraphs are not children of the h2 tag, but `siblings`
Also you are not removing the large class at all.

```
$('h2').click(function()
  {
    $(this).addClass('h2Color');
    $(this).siblings('p').addClass('large');
  });
```